# How to parse URL when using the pager plugin with AJAX

Tags: php, regex, tablesorter

I am trying to use the tablesorter pager plugin with AJAX but run into som problemes (or limitations) when trying to handle the AJAX request in my php backend.

If eg. the table is set up with a default sorting of

```
sortList: [ [0,1], [1,0] ]
```

I will get a URL like this on my AJAX request:

```
page=0&size=50&filter=fcol[6]=batteri&sort=col[0]=1&col[1]=0
```

In my php back end I do a

```
$cur_sort = $_GET['sort']
```

and get

```
col[0]=1
```

So the last part is missing - I guess since it contains a & char.

How do I get the entire `sort` string?

That said how is the string `col[0]=1&col[1]=0` best parsed? I need to extract the info that col 0 is to be sorter DESC and col 1 ASC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this;

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$data);
```

It will parse the url to an array;

Also; you should use empty `[]` instead of `[1]` and `[0]`

See more here: [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php)

Example:

```
$str = "page=0&size=50&filter=fcol[6]=batteri&sort=col[0]=1&col[1]=0";

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['page'];  // echo 0
```

And to answer your question; it is correct; is echoing `col[0]=1` because you are dividing with `&` see here:

> &sort=col[0]=1 **&** col[1]=0;

An advice; use more names, instead.
You could use

> `&sort[]=1&sort[]=0;`

UPDATE:
To access the last one; you should do, simply;

```
$_GET['col'][1];
```

If you want to access, the last number in

```
$_GET['sort'];
```

You can do this;

```
$explode = explode('=',$_GET['sort']);
$end = end($explode);
echo $end; //it will outout 1
```

If you print your entire `query_String`, it will print this;

```
Array
(
    [page] => 0
    [size] => 50
    [filter] => fcol[6]=batteri
    [sort] => col[0]=1
    [col] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: My challange is that I have no control over the URL. It's generated by tablesorter so I have to make it work as it is.

Comment: +1, but the URL being used is malformed. Please see my answer as the pager does allow the URL to be much more customizable.

Comment: Yes. It is malformed.

Comment: I fixed the URL - it now looks like this `?page=0&size=50&fcol[1]=test&col[4]=0&col[5]=1` and the loop `foreach($_GET['col'] as $col => $dir) { ... }` does the job.
The trick to fixing the URL was the `ajaxUrl` (Thanks to Mottie).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the `ajaxUrl` option is being used, but the output shared in the question doesn't look right.

I really have *no idea* how the string in the question is showing this format:

- `&sort=col[0]=1&col[1]=0` (where did `sort=` come from?)
- `&filter=fcol[6]=batteri` (where did `filter=` come from?)

If you look at how you can manipulate the [`ajaxUrl` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxurl), you will see this example:

```
ajaxUrl: "http://mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol}"
```

So say you have the following settings:

- page = 2
- size = 10
- `sortList` is set to `[[0,1],[3,0]]` (1st column descending sort, 4th column ascending sort)
- filters is set as `['','','fred']`

The resulting url passed to the server will look like this:

```
http://mydatabase.com?page=2&size=10&col[0]=1&col[3]=0&fcol[2]=fred
```

The `col` part of the `{sortList:col}` placeholder sets the sorted column name passed to the URL & the `fcol` part of `{filterList:fcol}` placeholder sets the filter for the set column. So those are not fixed names.

If the above method for using the `ajaxUrl` string doesn't suit your needs, you can leave those settings out of the `ajaxUrl` and instead use the [`customAjaxUrl` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-customajaxurl) to modify the URL as desired. Here is a simple example (*I know this is not a conventional method*):

```
ajaxUrl: "http://mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}",
// modify the url after all processing has been applied
customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
  var config = table.config,
      // convert [[0,1],[3,0]] into "0-1-3-0"
      sort = [].concat.apply( [], config.sortList ).join('-'),
      // convert [ '', '', 'fred' ] into "--fred"
      filter = config.lastSearch.join('-');
  // send the server the current page
  return url += '&sort=' + sort + '&filter=' + filter 
}
```

With the same settings, the resulting URL will now look like this:

```
http://mydatabase.com?page=2&size=10&sort=0-1-3-0&filter=--fred
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own best solution so far, but it's not really elegant:

```
if (preg_match_all("/[^f]col\[\d+]=\d+/", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] AS $sortinfo) {
        if (preg_match_all("/\d+/", $sortinfo, $matches)) {
            if(count($matches[0]) == 2) {
                echo "Col: ".$matches[0][0]."<br/>";
                echo "Order: ".$matches[0][1]."<br/>";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It gives me the info I need

```
Col: 0
Order: 1
Col: 1
Order: 0
```

But is clumbsy. Is there a better way?